# Jira unable to find any import for which would match for login via restAPI in java

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I wanted to create simple JIRA login via rest java client and dispaly issue. I followed tutorial on Atlassian website.

My java :

```
   import com.atlassian.jira.testkit.client.restclient.Issue;

    public class UniRest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            final AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
            final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication("http://vle.atlassian.com", "admin", "admin");
            try {
                final Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue("TST-7").claim();
                System.out.println(issue);
            }
            finally {
                // cleanup the restClient
                restClient.close();
            }
        }
 }
```

my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.plugins.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>UniRestTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-m19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-m8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am searching for an aswear or fix for hours. Can't really find it. Its clearly I am doing something wrong or I miss somewhere something. Could you help me get this working ?

Problem is I just can't find any import for `JiraRestClient` and `AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory` that would solve my problem.

Error's I am getting are like :

> Error:(6, 15) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class
>   AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory   location: class UniRest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this answer from atlassian forum: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/24291459/cannot-create-asynchronousjirarestclientfactory

Comment: Thank you. I made stupid misstake. Forget to add <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>atlassian-public</id>
            <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>